# .apk renamed to .bin on device

Tags: android, apache, download, apk, filenames

I want to distribute an .apk file to a list of beta testers. I uploaded on my Apache-powered web server and modified .htaccess:

AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk

When downloading from Windows+Firefox, the file is downloaded as expected.
When downloading from Android device + Chrome, the file is renamed to .bin.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I have no evidence that this is the case, but I suspect its a security feature of Chrome to prevent people from downloading and installing random APKs on their devices.

Comment: I have sent android app (.apk) through mail. And it does not change the extension and it works fine .

Comment: According to this link http://www.joet3ch.com/blog/2010/08/20/deploying-android-apps-from-your-apache-server/ you should be modifying your httpd.conf file on the Apache server